# Batch findstr to find a number

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to get the revision number from a `svn update` command output. In the file `tmpFile.txt` I've got the string `At revision 58998.`

I've run the following command:

```
findstr /r "\<[0-9][0-9]*\>" "tmpFile.txt"
```

and I've got

```
At revision 58998.
```

Also, running with

```
findstr /r /o "\<[0-9][0-9]*\>" "tmpFile.txt"
```

I get

```
0:At revision 58998.
```

What's going on and how can I get only the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINDSTR prints out the entire line that matches. It is not able to extract just the matching portion of the line.

You can use FOR /F to parse the output and get just the number.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=. " %%A in (
  'findstr /rc:"At revision [0-9][0-9]*\." "tmpFile.txt"'
) do echo %%A
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a `findstr` solution, but it works :)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (tmpFile.txt) do (
set num=%%a
set num=!num:.=!
)
echo !num!
```

This will also remove the `.` from the end.

If your not bothered about the `.` use

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (tmpFile.txt) do echo %%a
```

or for cmd line (no batch)

```
for /f "tokens=3" %a in (tmpFile.txt) do echo %a
```

Comment: You may also remove the `.` this way: `for /f "tokens=3 delims=. " %a in (tmpFile.txt) do echo %a`